# Javascript: Using a Provider when using promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-storage

I'm uploading a camera picture to a Firebase Storage bucket. When its done, i retrieve the image-url to display it in my view. The current Coding looks like this:

```
  takePicture() {
    this.camera.getPicture(this.cameraOptions)
      .then(data => {
        let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        let imageName = this.imageSrv.generateUUID();
        let imageRef = storageRef.child(`${this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}/${imageName}.jpg`);
        imageRef.putString(base64Image, 'data_url').then(data => {
          imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(data => { this.url = data.toString(); })
        }
        )
      });
  }
```

It works, but it is not really great. I would like to put the coding to handle the database into a provider. How can this be achieved when using promises on the firebase storage? I cant directly access and return the URL in the providers methods because of the async handling:

```
getURL( userID: string, imageName: string) {
   let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
   let imageRef = storageRef.child(`${userId}/${imageId}.jpg`);
   return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
}
```

I would also like to do this for N images to view an image gallery.
Thank you in advance.